# NHibernate Criteria - how correctly use group by statement?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

I've got problem. I need to select from database records for people with ids which are in list externalIds. After that I need to select for every person only 1 record with the newest StartTime. I tried for example with SetProjection (GroupProperty and Max property) but the result is that it return me only list of StartTime when I need list of PersonnelPresence. My method look like:

```
public IList<PersonnelPresence> GetLastPersonnelPresencesForPeopleExternalIds(IList<string> externalIds)
{
            ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(PersonnelPresence), "pp").CreateCriteria("pp.Person", "p")
                .Add(Restrictions.In("p.ExternalId", externalIds.ToList()))
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("p.Id"))
                .Add(Projections.Max("pp.StartTime")));

            return criteria.List<Object>() as List<PersonnelPresence>;
}
```

Has anyone any idea how solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while, but still I'd like to try and help a little.

With complex queries such as these, I find that it helps to type the SQL first; once you have the SQL statement that gives you the results you want, it is easier to translate the query to ICriteria.

If possible, I recommend using the Query (not QueryOver) syntax of FluentNHibernate, as this is much easier to maintain and more flexible with complex cases such as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so if anyone would want something like that, I managed to solve by separating the query in two.

Something like that:

```
public IList<PersonnelPresence> GetLastPersonnelPresencesForPeopleExternalIds(IList<string> externalIds)
{
    var criteriaPersonnelPresenceNewest = DetachedCriteria.For<PersonnelPresence>("PP_")
                                                .Add(Restrictions.In("PP_.ExternalId", externalIds.ToArray()()))
                                                .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("PP_.ExternalId", "PP2_.ExternalId"))//to compare with the query down below
                                                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                                                                          .Add(Projections.Max("PP_.StartTime"))
                                                );

var criteriaPersonnelPresence = Session.CreateCriteria<PersonnelPresence>("PP2_")                                                   
                                        .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("PP2_.StartTime", criteriaPersonnelPresenceNewest))
                                        .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                                                                  .Add(Projections.Property("PP2_.Id"))
                                                                  .Add(Projections.Property("PP2_.StartTime"))
                                        )
                                        .ToList<PersonnelPresence>();

return criteriaPersonnelPresence;
}
```